# PHP ftp_nlist stuck on Rootfolder

Tags: php, ftp

I'm having a very strange Problem with a new Script of mine. It's just intended to list all files in a specific Folder but from ftp_nlist all i get in return are the folders located on the Root of the FTP!

Here's a snipped of the code

```
<?php
  $ftpServer = "192.168.10.190";
  $ftpUser = "user1";
  $ftpUser = "somePass";
  $remoteFilePath = "/SomeFolder/";

  $conn_id = ftp_connect($ftpServer) or die("<span style='color:#FF0000'><h2>Couldn't connect to $ftpServer</h2></span>");
  $login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftpUser, $ftpPass) or die("<span style='color:#FF0000'><h2>You do not have access to this ftp server!</h2></span>");
  $files = ftp_nlist( $conn_id, $remoteFilePath );
  echo print_r($files)."<br>";
?>
```

Anyone with an Idea what is going on?!

**Solution**

I've found it out on my own. All i had to do was putting the ftp_nlist in a if clause that changed to the desired directory ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP FTP directory listing error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/872651/php-ftp-directory-listing-error)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$remoteFilePath = "./SomeFolder/";
```

with the dot for explicitly referring to the current directory.

Comment: I have done this too but it' didn't work but i found the solution myself thx anyway

Comment: Then please provide your solution for others. Thanks.

Comment: I'd be curious to find out what the problem was? Having this same issue myself.